# what is the probability for a green marble to be drawn?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Bag A contains 3 green marbles and 2 red marbles.
Bag B contains 4 green marbles and 5 red marbles.
choose one bag randomly and pick one marble from it.
what is the probability for a green marble to be drawn?

Comment: You haven't said how you are drawing (though your answer is clearly wrong no matter what you had in mind...it's bigger than $1$).  Are you choosing (uniformly) randomly between the bags?  Something else?

Comment: There isn't enough information here. What exactly is the drawing procedure? Are we drawing one marble -- but then from which bag? Or are we drwaing one marble from A and one marble from B? Or we doing something different? But in any case, your adding the two probabilities is wrong.

Comment: my question is being updated

Comment: @JC616 Welcome to Maths Stack Exchange. Please show your working and ensure that your question is properly formulated and articulated well in order to avoid being downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are equally likely to pick Bag A as Bag B, here is how I would approach this problem. There are two cases we must consider:

1. You randomly select Bag A and draw a green from it
2. You randomly select Bag B and draw a green from it

Since these events are mutually exclusive, we can just add up the probabilities of these cases.

$$
P(\text{Drawing a green from Bag A})=\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{5} = \frac{3}{10} \\
P(\text{Drawing a green from Bag B})=\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4}{9} = \frac{4}{18}
$$

Adding these two up gives us the answer:

$$
\frac{3}{10} + \frac{4}{18} = \frac{27}{90} + \frac{20}{90} = \frac{47}{90}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly:

$P(\text{Green}) = \left(\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4}{9}\right) = \frac{47}{90}$

Comment: it is what I think too